# PHP iterate thru doctrine object inside array

Tags: php, oop, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a doctrine array which holds an object, and that object contains properties, I'm trying to access each one but something doesn't work right.

Here is the `print_r()` of `$users`:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Entities\Months Object ( 
        [id:Entities\Months:private] => 12
        [month:Entities\Months:private] => December 
        [units:Entities\Months:private] => 1 
    ) 
)
```

Here is the code:

```
$q = $this->doctrine->em->createQuery("select m from Entities\Months m where m.month = 'December'");
$users = $q->getResult();
print_r($users);
foreach($users as $key => $value){
    echo $value->id:Entities\Months:private;
}
```

This throws an error probably as the characters are messing up the property name. I tried this as well:

```
echo $value->{'id:Entities\Months:private'};
```

But says:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Entities\Months::$id:Entities\Months:private

Filename: controllers/data.php

Line Number: 264
```

So if anyone knows how to read these objects to manipulate them it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually with Doctrine, all properties of entities are private or protected. You can access them with the getter `$value->getId();`

So your code should be

```
$q = $this->doctrine->em->createQuery("select m from Entities\Months m where m.month = 'December'");
    $users = $q->getResult();
    print_r($users);
    foreach($users as $key => $value){
        echo $value->getId();
    }
```

Comment: perfect! works great thx for that info, i have getters and setters, was just not thinking about using them. Though a simple reading of the key would work